# From Siena on GAE using Play framework 1.X to which database/api/module on Heroku using Play 2.0?

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, siena

I've really enjoyed using Play framework 1.X on Google App Engine with Siena for data storing.

Now I'm looking into using Play framework 2.0 for a new project. As Play isn't ready for GAE I'm going to try out Heroku. What are my options if I want the simplicity of annotating my classes like with Siena and having them stored in some NoSQL database at Heroku? Can I use the built in data storage support in Play or are there any modules that support some NoSQL addon at Heroku?

Edit:

I want to use Play's Java API (not Scala).

Answer (score 1):

With Play 1.2.X you could use the "[MongoLab](https://addons.heroku.com/mongolab)" add-on to Heroku together with the [Morphia Play module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia).

As for Play2, I would suggest checking out the "[salat](https://github.com/novus/salat)" plugin to access your MongoDB's. See https://github.com/zenexity/Zest for an example play2 app using salat. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your models are not too specific to GAE, you can switch to postgres quite easily with Siena. It's one of its main purpose ;)

Comment: Yep. I might try out that. But I would prefer to use a NoSQL database in this case.